# How to use function with foreach in .hbs (Handlebar)?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I am trying using function for .hbs file but not able to do that.Below is the code which i want to use in handlebar

```
        if(userData.length!=0){
        var i=1;
        userData.forEach(function(data){
```

I try to use below code but that havn't work

```
 {{#each userData(function(data))}}
       <h1>{{userData}}</h1>
       {{log data.Dimension_4_Score}}
        {{/each}}
```

Comment: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each usethis .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do it using below code

```
<div>
    {{#each userData}}
               <tr>
            <td>{{User_ID}}</td>
            <td>{{Team_Name}}</td>
            <td>{{Dimension_1_Score}}</td>
            <td>{{Dimension_2_Score}}</td>
            <td>{{Dimension_3_Score}}</td>
            <td>{{Dimension_4_Score}}</td>
            <td>{{Total_Score_Persentage}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easy method to use **

```
{{#each data}}
  <div>
    <p>{{this.username}}</p>
    <img src='/images/{{this.image}}' width="100px"/>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```